# How do I update packages on Red Hat Linux?

Tags: software-installation

In my current computer science class we are programming in C. When I ssh into my school servers running Red Hat Linux, the compiler and debugger are outdated compared to my Mac's (for example, `clang` is not recognized on my school server).

How do I find out about and get the most up to date environment? Is it just a user preference sort of thing?

Comment: As much as I like clang, if I were running the course I would not want alternative compilers on the student server.  Too many issues with people saying 'but it compiled on X'...

Answer (score 2):

No it's not just a user preference. You can see if there's a package available that provides `clang` using the package management tool YUM.

```
$ yum search clang
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, changelog, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
=============================== N/S matched: clang ============================
clang-devel.i686 : Header files for clang
clang-devel.x86_64 : Header files for clang
clang-doc.noarch : Documentation for Clang
csmock-plugin-clang.noarch : csmock plug-in providing the support for Clang
clang.i686 : A C language family front-end for LLVM
clang.x86_64 : A C language family front-end for LLVM
clang-analyzer.x86_64 : A source code analysis framework
clang-analyzer.noarch : A source code analysis framework
csclng.x86_64 : A compiler wrapper that runs Clang in background

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

From the above output you can see that there's several packages available that include the string "clang".

If the package `clang` were already installed and it were lagging behind in versions, you could use `yum check-update clang` to see if there were a newer version available.

#### Installing updates

If the package isn't installed or is lagging behind in versions, you need to be an administrator to install and/or update it, however. This means that you either need to have the ability to become the "root" user on the system, or have `sudo` privileges.

The command `sudo` is a facility that's typically included with Unix systems so that administrator functions can be doled out to other users, without having to give them full "root" access, or the root user's password.

#### Installing as non-root

You can compile from source and install many tools into your home directory `$HOME`. The compiler, `clang`, is one such tool. Details on how to do this are covered in this Stack Overflow Q&A titled: [Install Clang as User (no Root Privileges)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681385/install-clang-as-user-no-root-privileges). Additionally you can use this script that's hosted on GitHub, titled: [install-clang](https://github.com/rsmmr/install-clang), which will do all the heavy lifting of downloading, configuring, and installing `clang` into your `$HOME` directory too.

Answer (score 0):

From `yum` man pages:

> - `update [package1] [package2] [...]`
>
> update
>
> If run without any packages, update will update every currently installed package. If one or more packages or package globs are
>   specified, Yum will only update the listed packages. While updating
>   packages, yum will ensure that all dependencies are satisfied. (See
>   Specifying package names for more information) If the packages or
>   globs specified match to packages which are not currently installed
>   then update will not install them. update operates on groups, files,
>   provides and filelists just like the "install" command.

So the command you would want to run is:

```
sudo yum update
```

Please note this will only work on RPM-based distributions, which is what Red Hat Linux is. However, updating software system-wide requires root access, which your school's system administrator may not have granted you.

Comment: But you need root access!

Comment: Thats what you asked, how to get the most up to date terminal environment, thats the way to do it.

Comment: As far as sudo, ask the server admin if he can provide the most up to date packages for you

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will talk to my professor and ask about this.